# Who are the mind born daughters or Manasi Kanyas of Lord Brahma?

Tags: brahma

Lord Brahma had many mind born sons who were given charge of populating the world. However there is some mention of Lord Brahmas daughters like Shatarupa, wife of Swayambhuva Manu; Ahalya wife of Gautama Rishi and Lopamudra, wife of sage Agastya.

I came across one Puranic reference which says that Svadha, wife of the Pitris is also a Manasi Kanya or mind born daughter of Lord Brahma.

Besides these who are the mind born daughters of Lord Brahma and what were their stories?

(I’m not looking for any answers calling Devi Saraswati as a daughter of Brahma)